# How to aviod SQL Injection on CodeIgniter CRUD My_Model

Tags: database, codeigniter

I m using PHP CodeIgniter with CRUD MY_Modal. i want to prevent SQL Injection. How I deal with.

```
$condition_array=array('email'=> $this->input->post('user_id'),'password' => $this->input->post('password'),);
$user= $this->Service_seeker_m->get_by($condition_array,TRUE);
```

in this way i m calling the my model(`Service_seeker_m`) which is include `MY_Modal`(CRUD).

can any body help me to solve my query.
thanks

Comment: This code able to avoid sql injection. What else you want??

Comment: R u sure. it means no body can hamper the database by SQL Injection

Comment: have you tried sql injection on given code?? The query escaping already done with codeigniter active records queries.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. yes i have tried but i want to sure. is there any other way to prevent. So i will free.

Comment: It will depend on how you wrote the query in `Service_seeker_m ->get_by()`. We need to see the code inside that function.

Comment: These references might also help you: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797613/sql-injection-and-codeigniter?rq=1), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917831/prevent-sql-injections-in-codeigniter?rq=1)

Comment: Actually i m using general  CRUD Modal of CodeIgniter where get_by()  function is define.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some suggestion regarding your query.

#### escaping-queries:

Here is the [link to documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)

It’s a very good security practice to escape your data before submitting it into your database. CodeIgniter has three methods that help you do this:

1. `$this->db->escape()` This function determines the data type so that it can escape only string data. It also automatically adds single quotes around the data so you don’t have to:

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($title).")";
   ```
2. `$this->db->escape_str()` This function escapes the data passed to it, regardless of type. Most of the time you’ll use the above function rather than this one. Use the function like this:

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($title)."')";
   ```
3. $this->db->escape_like_str() This method should be used when strings are to be used in LIKE conditions so that LIKE wildcards (‘%’, ‘_’) in the string are also properly escaped.

   ```
   $search = '20% raise';
   $sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%" .
   $this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%' ESCAPE '!'";
   ```

> The `escape_like_str()` method uses `‘!’` (exclamation mark) to escape
>   special characters for LIKE conditions. Because this method escapes
>   partial strings that you would wrap in quotes yourself, it cannot
>   automatically add the ESCAPE '!' the condition for you, and so you’ll
>   have to manually do that.

#### Query-bindings

Here is the [link to documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings) It is described in brief to understand properly.